# Find number of data points in each series in highcharts

Tags: highcharts

Is there a way to determine the number of data points in each series of a Highcharts chart?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming that you want to get from the first serie.

```
console.log(chart.series[0].data.length);
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/ricardolohmann/tJ2Ak/)

Answer (score 2):

Using jQuery and assuming you've defined the chart as a variable named `chart` ...

```
$.each(
    chart.series,
    function(){
        console.log(this.name + ": " + this.data.length + " data points.");
    }
);
```